# RestKit POST object to Python

Tags: python, ios, flask, restkit

I am using RestKit for iOS to perform a POST to my Python (Flask) server.  The POST arguments is a set of nested dictionaries.  When I create my hierarchical argument object on the client side and perform the post, there are no errors.  But on the server side, the form data is flattened into a single set of keys which are themselves indexed strings:

```
@interface TestArgs : NSObject

@property (strong, nonatomic) NSDictionary *a;
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSDictionary *b;

@end


RKObjectMapping *requestMapping = [RKObjectMapping requestMapping]; // objectClass == NSMutableDictionary
[requestMapping addAttributeMappingsFromArray:@[
 @"a.name",
 @"a.address",
 @"a.gender",
 @"b.name",
 @"b.address",
 @"b.gender",
 ]];

RKRequestDescriptor *requestDescriptor = [RKRequestDescriptor requestDescriptorWithMapping:requestMapping objectClass:[TestArgs class] rootKeyPath:nil];

RKObjectManager *manager = [RKObjectManager managerWithBaseURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://localhost:5000"]];
[manager addRequestDescriptor:requestDescriptor];

NSDictionary *a = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                   @"Alexis",    @"name",
                   @"Boston",   @"address",
                   @"female",     @"gender",
                   nil];
NSDictionary *b = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                   @"Chris",    @"name",
                   @"Boston",   @"address",
                   @"male",     @"gender",
                   nil];
TestArgs *tArgs = [[TestArgs alloc] init];
tArgs.a = a;
tArgs.b = b;

[manager postObject:tArgs path:@"/login" parameters:nil success:nil failure:nil];
```

On the server side, the POST body is this:

```
{'b[gender]': u'male', 'a[gender]': u'female', 'b[name]': u'Chris', 'a[name]': u'Alexis', 'b[address]': u'Boston', 'a[address]': u'Boston'}
```

When what I really want is this:

```
{'b': {'gender' : u'male', 'name': u'Chris', 'address': u'Boston'}, 'a': {'gender': u'female', 'name': u'Alexis', 'address': u'Boston'}}
```

Why is the POST body not maintaining its hierarchy on the server side?  Is this an error with my client side encoding logic?  On the server side with Flask decoding the JSON?  Any ideas?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error is with the client side mapping. Your mapping needs to represent the structure of the data you want and the relationships it contains. Currently the mapping uses keypaths which effectively hide the structural relationships.

You need 2 mappings:

1. The dictionary of parameters
2. The container of the dictionaries

The mappings are defined as:

```
paramMapping = [RKObjectMapping requestMapping];
containerMapping = [RKObjectMapping requestMapping];

[paramMapping addAttributeMappingsFromArray:@[
 @"name",
 @"address",
 @"gender",
 ]];

RKRelationshipMapping *aRelationship = [RKRelationshipMapping
                                       relationshipMappingFromKeyPath:@"a"
                                       toKeyPath:@"a"
                                       withMapping:paramMapping];
RKRelationshipMapping *bRelationship = [RKRelationshipMapping
                                       relationshipMappingFromKeyPath:@"b"
                                       toKeyPath:@"b"
                                       withMapping:paramMapping]

[containerMapping addPropertyMapping:aRelationship];
[containerMapping addPropertyMapping:bRelationship];
```

Then your request descriptor is defined using the container mapping.